# How to parse json data in jquery ajax success?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax

```
info = {
    'phone_number': '123456',
    'personal_detail': {'foo': foo, 'bar': bar},
    'is_active': 1,
    'document_detail': {'baz': baz, 'saz': saz},
    'is_admin': 1,
    'email': 'foo@bar.com'
}

return HttpResponse(
    simplejson.dumps({'success':'True', 'result':info}),
    mimetype='application/javascript')


if(data["success"] === "True") {
    alert(data[**here I want to display personal_detail and document_details**]);
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Try and use the jQuery template plugin (http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/).

Comment: This is a confusing post because you have python and javascript in the same code block and the code for making the ajax request is missing.

What is the url you're passing to getJSON? Also you can use the native bool types in json, True in python and true in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for [jquery parse json](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/), if I understand the question properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON('/ajax_url/',
    {
        'some_data': 'Some Value'
    },
    function(result){
        alert(result.personal_detail.foo);
    }
);
```

`$.getJSON` sends a `GET` request to the provided url (first argument) with urlencoded params (second argument) you provide, and on success, calls the success function (third argument) with the JSON decoded result from the server (`result`).

This is a shortcut version of using `$.ajax` and manually calling `$.parseJSON`, etc.